# Select count of some columns where a condition is valid

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query i'm currently working on:

```
SELECT COUNT(approved) AS 'approve'
 , COUNT(approved) AS 'deny'
 , COUNT(approved) AS 'unset'
FROM `approval`
WHERE 'approve' = 'Approved'
 AND 'deny' = 'Denied'
 AND 'unset' = 'Unset
```

I want the counts to record all the times that the enum approved = Approved, Denied, and Unset

Comment: can you provide table schema and desired sample output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With mysql, there's a neat way of doing what is termed a [pivot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table):

```
SELECT
    SUM(approved = 'Approved') approve,
    SUM(approved = 'Denied') deny,
    SUM(approved = 'Unset') unset
FROM approval
WHERE approved in ('Approved', 'Denied', 'Unset')
```

This works because in mysql true is 1 and false is 0, so summing a condition counts how many times the condition is true.

The where clause is optional.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN approved = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approve,
SUM(CASE WHEN approved = 'Denied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS deny,
SUM(CASE WHEN approved = 'Unset' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS unset
FROM approval
WHERE approved IN ('Approved','Denied','Unset')
```

Comment: yes, this probably makes more sense... but you should explain why you use sum not count imo

Comment: The syntax of Bohemian's answer is cleaner, and while there are often reasons to avoid implicit conversions between data types, I doubt if there is any negative consequence here.

The only reason to use my SQL would be cross-RDBMS compatibility.